# Greasemonkey Reload Section of a Page (AJAX?)

Tags: ajax, greasemonkey, reload

I'd like to reload a section of a page (a div) using Greasemonkey every few seconds without reloading the entire page. I know this is possible with GM_xmlhttpRequest and JQuery, but I'm not sure how to specify which section or div on the page to reload and or the best way to go about it.

What's the best way to use AJAX to reload a particular div given an ID?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = document.location.href.toString();
$("#id").load(url+ ' #id');
```

Eh. Good enough. Not much faster than a full refresh though.